# Can't get rid of Lubuntu's Login Greeter

Tags: unity, login, lightdm, login-screen, unity-greeter

If I lock my computer or logout, when I log back in, I want to see unity-greeter. But I can't seem to get rid of Lubuntu's greeter upon logging in.

I once installed Lubuntu but have since uninstalled it. I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling lightdm, reconfiguring it, reinstalling unity-greeter, running `apt-get purge lightdm-gtk-greeter`, but no matter what I do, I cannot get rid of Lubuntu's greeter.

Any ideas how to erase the lubuntu greeter and remove every trace of it, so I only see the unity greeter? Short of a full re-install.

Thanks.

Edit: Contents of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=ali
autologin-user-timeout=0
autologin-session=lightdm-autologin
allow-guest=false
greeter-hide-users=true
user-session=ubuntu 
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up lightdm.conf:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

You must have the following settings under [SeatDefaults]:

```
user-session=ubuntu 
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Save and reboot.

---

**UPDATE**
Open your Terminal, Enter below command

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm-gtk-greeter*
sudo apt-get purge lightdm 
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:lightdm-gtk-greeter-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

Install lightdm

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Reconfigure lightdm and unity-greeter

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm unity-greeter
```

Comment: No effect. I've edited my question to include the contents of  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Comment: check the update

Comment: Now, it first shows the unity screen, and after I login, then i get the lubuntu screen again and I have to enter the password a 2nd time into it. So unity-greeter is working, but the lubuntu-greeter is also still there and I need to erase it somehow.

Comment: The output is: http://www.pastekit.com/#!ViewPage;hash=jR0oWY . purge lxdm says 'Package 'lxdm' is not installed, so not removed`. May be its a different desktop manager that needs to be removed?

Comment: `sudo  /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -g lightdm-greeter`

Comment: sudo: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults: command not found

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm unity-greeter` and reboot yout computer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23943/discussion-between-new-user-and-click-upvote).

Comment: Same thing, it shows unity at first, and when I log in, then it makes me log into the other login manager. That one has a button saying 'unlock' and a dropdown of user names including 'guest session'. Any ideas what package its in?

Answer (score 0):

Use of /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf is depreciated. You must now create a file in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d like so.

**save any unsaved files before you begin**

Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
echo "[SeatDefaults]" | sudo tee /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
echo "greeter-session=unity-greeter" | sudo tee -a /etc/lightdm.conf.d
sudo chmod +x /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
```

Now, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, sign in with your username and password and execute the following command to restart lightdm:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```